Проблемы с import javascript
Я хочу подключиться к БД mysql, но у меня проблемы с импортом библиотеки mysql2. Если написать:
import mysql from 'mysql2';

будет ошибка:
Uncaught TypeError: Спецификатор «mysql2» являлся голым спецификатором, но не был переназначен на что-либо. Связанные спецификаторы модуля должны начинаться с «./», «../» или «/».

Если же указать конкретную папку или файл, то появляется такая ошибка:
Загрузка модуля по адресу «http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/my» была заблокирована из-за неразрешенного MIME-типа («text/html»).

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Diagram Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/properties-panel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/menubar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/toolbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/loginForm.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../node_modules/@joint/plus/joint-plus.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">
    <div class="slider"></div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button class="login">Вход</button>
        <button class="signup">Регистрация</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-section">
        <div class="login-box">
            <input id="login-email" type="email"
                   class="email ele"
                   placeholder="почта">
            <input id="login-password" type="password"
                   class="password ele"
                   placeholder="пароль">
            <button id="loginbtn" class="clkbtn">Вход</button>
        </div>
        <div class="signup-box">
            <input id="name" type="text"
                   class="name ele"
                   placeholder="введите ваше имя">
            <input id="email" type="email"
                   class="email ele"
                   placeholder="введите вашу почту">
            <input id="password" type="password"
                   class="password ele"
                   placeholder="пароль">
            <input id="confirm-password" type="password"
                   class="password ele"
                   placeholder="подтвердите пароль">
            <button id="regbtn" class="clkbtn">Регистрация</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="geHeaderContainer">
        <div class="geMenubarContainer">
            <a class="geIcon"></a>
            <div class="geTextDiv">
                <a id="title" class="geItem"></a>
            </div>
            <img src="./icons/header.png">

            <div class="geMenubar">
                <a class="geItem">Файл
                    <div id="file" class="geDropdown">
                        <div class="geDropdownItem" id="open-option">Открыть</div>
                        <div class="geDropdownItem" id="save-option">Сохранить</div>
                        <div class="geDropdownItem" id="exit-option">Выход</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="geItem">Правка
                    <div class="geDropdown">
                        <div id="undo" class="geDropdownItem">Отменить</div>
                        <div id="redo" class="geDropdownItem">Повторить</div>
                        <div id="cut" class="geDropdownItem">Вырезать</div>
                        <div id="copy" class="geDropdownItem">Копировать</div>
                        <div id="paste" class="geDropdownItem">Вставить</div>
                        <div id="delete" class="geDropdownItem">Удалить</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="geItem">Вид
                    <div class="geDropdown">
                        <div id="zoom" class="geDropdownItem">Увеличить</div>
                        <div id="zoom out" class="geDropdownItem">Уменьшить</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="geItem">Положение
                    <div class="geDropdown">
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">Вверх</div>
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">Вниз</div>
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">Влево</div>
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">Вправо</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="geItem">Дополнительно
                    <div class="geDropdown">
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">Настройки</div>
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">Справка</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a class="geItem">Помощь
                    <div class="geDropdown">
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">О программе</div>
                        <div class="geDropdownItem">Поддержка</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="geToolbarContainer">
            <div class="geToolbar">

                <a id="zoom-scale" class="geLabel" title="Масштаб (Alt+Mousewheel)">
                    100%
                    <img src="../icons/arrow.gif">
        
                </a>
                <div id="scale-dropdown">
                    <a class="scale-option" data-scale="0.25">25%</a>
                    <a class="scale-option" data-scale="0.5">50%</a>
                    <a class="scale-option" data-scale="0.75">75%</a>
                    <a class="scale-option" data-scale="1">100%</a>
                    <a class="scale-option" data-scale="1.25">125%</a>
                    <a class="scale-option" data-scale="1.5">150%</a>
                    <a class="scale-option" data-scale="1.75">175%</a>
                </div>
                <div class="geSeparator"></div>
                <a id="zoom-button" class="geLabel" title="Увеличить">
                    <img src="../icons/glass1.png"></img>
                </a>
                <a id="unzoom-button" class="geLabel" title="Уменьшить">
                    <img src="../icons/glass2.png"></img>
                </a>
                <div class="geSeparator"></div>
                <a id='undo-button'class="geLabel" title="Отменить (Ctrl+Z)">
                    <img src="../icons/undo.png"></img>
                </a>
                <a id='redo-button' class="geLabel" title="Вернуть (Ctrl+Y)">
                    <img src="../icons/revert.png"></img>
                </a>
                <div class="geSeparator"></div>
                <a id='delete-button' class="geLabel" title="Удалить (Delete)">
                    <img src="../icons/delete.png"></img>
                </a>
                <div class="geSeparator"></div>

                <input type="color" id="color-pick-input" title="Цвет сетки" value="#ffffff">
                <input type="range" id="line-width-input" title="Размер сетки" min="1" max="100" value="20">
                <span id="range-value"></span>
                <a id="textBox" class="geLabel" title="Добавить текст">
                    <img src="../icons/text.png"></img>
                </a>
                <div class="geSeparator"></div>
                <a id="clear-button" class="geLabel" title="очистить">
                    <img src="../icons/clear.png"></img>
                </a>
                <a id="save-button" class="geLabel" title="сохранить">
                    <img src="../icons/save.png"></img>
                </a>
                <a id="open-button" class="geLabel" title="открыть">
                    <img src="icons/open.png"></img>
                </a>
                <div class="geSeparator"></div>
                <select id="line-connection-type">
                    <option value="">Тип соединения</option>
                    <option value="manhattan">Manhattan</option>
                    <option value="metro">Metro</option>
                    <option value="normal">Normal</option>
                    <option value="orthogonal">Orthogonal</option>
                    <option value="rightAngle">Orthogonal Router with Given Direction (Right Angle)</option>
                </select>   
                <select id="saveSelect">
                    <option value="">Сохранить как</option>
                    <option value="json">JSON</option>
                    <option value="svg">SVG</option>
                    <option value="png">PNG</option>
                    <option value="jpg">JPG</option>
                </select>   
            </div>
           
        </div>
</div>
    

    <div id="sidebar">
        <img id="btn-toggle-menu" src="../icons/next.png"></img>
        <h3>Фигуры</h3>
        
        <a class="geTitle" >Избранное</a>
        <a class="geTitle" >Общие
        </a>   
        <div class="geSidebar">
                
            <a class="geItem" title="прямая линия" data-shape="line">
                <img src="../mainFigures/line.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="прямоугольник" data-shape="rectangle">
                <img src="../mainFigures/rectangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="закругленный прямоугольник" data-shape="rounded-rectangle">
                <img src="../mainFigures/rounded-rectangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="круг" data-shape="circle">
                <img src="../mainFigures/circle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="эллипс" data-shape="ellipse">
                <img src="../mainFigures/ellipse.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="треугольник" data-shape="triangle">
                <img src="../mainFigures/triangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="трапеция" data-shape="trapezium">
                <img src="../mainFigures/trapezium.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="комментарий" data-shape="90trapezium">
                <img src="../mainFigures/90trapezium.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="ромб" data-shape="rhomb">
                <img src="../mainFigures/rhomb.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="параллелограмм" data-shape="parallelogram">
                <img src="../mainFigures/parallelogram.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="пятиугольник" data-shape="pentagon">
                <img src="../mainFigures/pentagon.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="шестиугольник" data-shape="hexagon">
                <img src="../mainFigures/hexagon.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="цилиндр" data-shape="cylinder">
                <img src="../mainFigures/cylinder.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="односторонняя стрелка" data-shape="arrow">
                <img src="../mainFigures/arrows.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="двусторонняя стрелка" data-shape="double-arrow">
                <img src="../mainFigures/double-arrow.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="криволинейная стрелка" data-shape="curved-arrow" >
                <img src="../mainFigures/curve-arrow.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="изображение" data-shape="image" >
                <img src="/icons/image-icon1.svg" ></img>
            </a>
        </div>  
        <a class="geTitle" >Блок-схема</a>
        <div class="geSidebar">          
            <a class="geItem" title="процесс" data-shape="process">
                <img src="../mainFigures/rectangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="альтернативный процесс" data-shape="alternative process">
                <img src="../block diagram/alternative process.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="решение/условие" data-shape="decision/condition">
                <img src="../mainFigures/rhomb.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="вход/выход" data-shape="inOutput">
                <img src="../mainFigures/parallelogram.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="определенный процесс" data-shape="predefined process">
                <img src="../block diagram/predefined process.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="эллипс" data-shape="internal storage">
                <img src="../block diagram/internal data.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="документ" data-shape="document">
                <img src="../block diagram/document.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="мульти-документ" data-shape="multi-document">
                <img src="../block diagram/multi-document.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="начало/конец" data-shape="start/end">
                <img src="../mainFigures/rounded-rectangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="подготовка" data-shape="preparation">
                <img src="../block diagram/preparation.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="сортировка" data-shape="sort">
                <img src="../block diagram/sort.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="ручной ввод" data-shape="manual input">
                <img src="../block diagram/manual input.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="ручная операция" data-shape="manual operation">
                <img src="../block diagram/manual operation.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="узел" data-shape="node">
                <img src="../mainFigures/circle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="ссылка" data-shape="link">
                <img src="../block diagram/link.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="карточка" data-shape="card">
                <img src="../block diagram/card.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="перфолента" data-shape="tape">
                <img src="../block diagram/tape.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="узел суммирования" data-shape="summing junction">
                <img src="../block diagram/summing junction.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="узел или" data-shape="or" >
                <img src="../block diagram/or.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="сопоставление" data-shape="collate" >
                <img src="../block diagram/collate.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="извлечение" data-shape="exctract/measurement" >
                <img src="../mainFigures/triangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="объединение" data-shape="merge/storage" >
                <img src="../mainFigures/triangle.png" style="transform: rotate(180deg);" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="сохраненные данные" data-shape="stored data" >
                <img src="../block diagram/stored data.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="память с последовательным доступом" data-shape="sequantional data" >
                <img src="../block diagram/sequantional data.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="база данных" data-shape="database" >
                <img src="../block diagram/database.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="память с прямым доступом" data-shape="direct data" >
                <img src="../block diagram/direct data.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="дисплей" data-shape="display" >
                <img src="../block diagram/display.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="annotation1" data-shape="annotation1" >
                <img src="../block diagram/annotation1.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="комментарий2" data-shape="annotation2" >
                <img src="../block diagram/annotation2.png" ></img>
            </a>
        </div>
        <a class="geTitle" >UML</a>
        <div class="geSidebar">
                
            <a class="geItem" title="класс" data-shape="class">
                <img src="mainFigures/line.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="интерфейс" data-shape="interface">
                <img src="mainFigures/rectangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="обьект" data-shape="rounded-rectangle">
                <img src="mainFigures/rounded-rectangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="круг" data-shape="circle">
                <img src="mainFigures/circle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="эллипс" data-shape="ellipse">
                <img src="mainFigures/ellipse.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="треугольник" data-shape="triangle">
                <img src="mainFigures/triangle.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="трапеция" data-shape="trapezium">
                <img src="mainFigures/trapezium.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="комментарий" data-shape="90trapezium">
                <img src="mainFigures/90trapezium.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="ромб" data-shape="rhomb">
                <img src="mainFigures/rhomb.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="параллелограмм" data-shape="parallelogram">
                <img src="mainFigures/parallelogram.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="пятиугольник" data-shape="pentagon">
                <img src="mainFigures/pentagon.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="шестиугольник" data-shape="hexagon">
                <img src="mainFigures/hexagon.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="цилиндр" data-shape="cylinder">
                <img src="mainFigures/cylinder.png" ></img>
            </a>

            <a class="geItem" title="односторонняя стрелка" data-shape="arrow">
                <img src="mainFigures/arrows.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="двусторонняя стрелка" data-shape="double-arrow">
                <img src="mainFigures/double-arrow.png" ></img>
            </a>
            <a class="geItem" title="криволинейная стрелка" data-shape="curved-arrow" >
                <img src="mainFigures/curve-arrow.png" ></img>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="diagram-container">
        <div id="canvas" >
        </div>
        <div id="radar" >
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="properties-panel">
        <h2>Стили элемента</h2>
        <label for="stroke-color">Цвет контура:</label>
        <input type="color" id="stroke-color"><br>
    
        <label for="fill-color">Цвет заливки:</label>
        <input type="color" id="fill-color"><br>
    
        <label for="line-width">Толщина линии:</label>
        <input type="number" id="line-width" min="1" max="10" value="1"><br>
        <label for="width">Длина:</label>
        <input type="number" id="width" min="1" max="1000" ><br>
        <label for="height">Ширина:</label>
        <input type="number" id="height" min="1" max="1000" ><br>
    
        <label for="line-style">Тип линии:</label>
        <select id="line-style">
            <option value="solid">Сплошная</option>
            <option value="dashed">Пунктирная</option>
            <option value="dotted">Точечная</option>
        </select><br>
    
        <label for="text-content">Текст:</label>
        <input type="text" id="text-content"><br>
    
        <label for="text-size">Размер текста:</label>
        <input type="number" id="text-size" min="8" max="24" value="12"><br>
    
        <label for="text-font">Шрифт текста:</label>
        <select id="text-font">
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
            <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
            <!-- Добавьте другие варианты шрифтов по вашему усмотрению -->
        </select><br>
    
        <label for="text-weight">Жирность текста:</label>
        <select id="text-weight">
            <option value="normal">Обычный</option>
            <option value="bold">Жирный</option>
        </select><br>
    
        <button id="apply-styles">Применить стили</button>
    </div>

    <script src="node_modules/@joint/plus/joint-plus.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="../js/login.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sql.js/1.5.0/sql-wasm.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

login.js:
import mysql from 'mysql2';


    let signup =  document.querySelector(".signup");
    let login = document.querySelector(".login");
    let slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
    let formSection = document.querySelector(".form-section");

    signup.addEventListener("click", () => {
        slider.classList.add("moveslider");
        formSection.classList.add("form-section-move");
    });
    
    login.addEventListener("click", () => {
        slider.classList.remove("moveslider");
        formSection.classList.remove("form-section-move");
    });

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        database: "diagramEditor",
        password: ""
      });
      connection.connect(function(err){
        if (err) {
           console.log("Ошибка: " + err.message);
        }
        else{
          console.log("Подключение к серверу MySQL успешно установлено");
        }
     });
      // закрытие подключения
 connection.end(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log("Ошибка: " + err.message);
    }
    console.log("Подключение закрыто");
  });

// Обработчик события для кнопки регистрации
document.getElementById('regbtn').addEventListener("click", async () => {
    // Получаем данные из полей формы
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    const confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirm-password").value;

    // Проверка корректности данных
    if (!name || !email || !password || !confirmPassword) {
        alert("Все поля должны быть заполнены.");
        return;
    }

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        alert("Пароли не совпадают.");
        return;
    }

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
        alert("Некорректный email.");
        return;
    }

    // Хеширование пароля (опционально)
    // const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);

    // Вставка данных в базу данных
    try {
        const sql = "INSERT INTO users(name, age) VALUES(?, ?)";
        connection.query(sql, user, function(err, results) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            else console.log("Данные добавлены");
        });
        alert("Регистрация успешна!");
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message.includes("UNIQUE constraint failed")) {
            alert("Email уже зарегистрирован.");
        } else {
            alert("Ошибка регистрации: " + error.message);
        }
    }

});

// Обработчик события для кнопки входа
        document.getElementById('loginbtn').addEventListener("click", async () => {
            // Получаем данные из полей формы
            const email = document.getElementById("login-email").value;
            const password = document.getElementById("login-password").value;

            // Проверка корректности данных
            if (!email || !password) {
                alert("Все поля должны быть заполнены.");
                return;
            }

            if (!validateEmail(email)) {
                alert("Некорректный email.");
                return;
            }

            // Проверка учетных данных
            const sql= `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?`;
            connection.query(sql, user, function(err, results) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                else console.log("Данные добавлены");
            });
             
            if (result.length > 0) {
                alert("Вход успешен!");
                document.querySelector('.container').classList.add('hidden');
            } else {
                alert("Неверный email или пароль.");
            }
        });


function validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}


Подключение к БД на стророне клиента работаьт не будет. mysql надо подключать на серверной части. Сервер осуществляет взаимодействие с БД, а клиет должен ходить к серверу за данными
